# How to quickly go back to Google Maps start screen

Tags: applications, google-maps, google-apps

When I first open Maps, I see a `Search` bar at the top where I can type in a place to go, I can click on the default quick-searches (Coffee, Restaurants, etc.), or I can just scroll on the map to look around. But if I start going deeper, e.g., looking at photos from restaurants, at one point I have to close a bunch of screens using a combination of back arrows, X's, and down-arrows to get back to the start screen.

I know they added a magnifying glass search icon  on some screens to quickly search for another place, but then I miss out on scrolling around with access to the default quick-searches.

Besides killing the app and reopening, **is their another way to quickly (with one tap) get back to the start screen?**  I've started to use Google Maps Go so I can open that and get to its start screen once, but after that it's the same problem.

---

(Mini rant: I find this particularly frustrating because a `Go Home` feature would be immensely useful in many Android apps, yet it basically doesn't exist as far as I can tell. But on websites, where it is almost completely useless, there's usually a pointless "Home" button.)

Comment: Welcome to modern (stupid) UX

Comment: I create a shortcut to the route on my home screen and tap that to get back instead of navigating through multiple backs etc//Good example of bad design by Google

Comment: This shortcut trick is handy when it's a new place I am going to and want to learn about it

Comment: Go back home (press the launcher's home button). Long press on Google Maps icon (on the drawer or shortcut), select Home.